# необъявленные идентификаторы и взаимозависимости классов

Tags: c++, инициализация

проблема такая.
Есть у меня класс Level, где есть метод столкновения с картой, он общий и для игрока и для врагов.
И класс врагов, где этот метод вызывается, ибо враг же должен по уровню бегать(как и игрок).

В итоге столкнулся с проблемой объявления классов, когда используется метод класса ДО описания самого класса.
Можно было бы просто поменять местами классы Entity и Level.
Но я хочу именно в классе Level хранить список врагов(хотя бы потому, что они хранятся вместе с уровнем Tiled Map Editor).

```
 class Entity
    {
    public:
        bool solid = true, visible = true;

        void update(Level& level)
        {
            level.col(*this);
        }

        Entity() {}
    };

    class Level
    {public:

        Level()
        {
            std::list <std::shared_ptr<Entity>> enemy;
            enemy.emplace_back(new Entity());
        }
        void col(Entity& player)
        {

        }
    };

    int main()
    {
        Level level;
    }
```

При компиляции ругается на необъявленный идентификатор.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Level; // предварительное объявление

class Entity
{
public:
    bool solid = true, visible = true;

    void update(Level& level); // идентификатор Level объявлен

    Entity() {}
};

class Level
{
public:
    Level()
    {
        std::list <std::shared_ptr<Entity>> enemy;
        enemy.emplace_back(new Entity());
    }
    void col(Entity& player)
    {

    }
};

void Entity::update(Level& level)
{
    level.col(*this); // идентификатор Level::col объявлен
}
```

Comment: Я так пытался, получил 
Ошибка C2027 использование неопределенного типа "Level"

Comment: @LexPartizan И какая строка в этом коде вызывает такую ошибку? Не забывайте приводить [mcve](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Спасибо, я не заметил, что Вы вынесли метод из класса, теперь всё работает!